# Variable inside repeating function keeps old values

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery and I can't seem to find a what is the cause of this issue.

I have a variable which gets a new value each time the function GameStart() runs, to this function I am trying to create a pause function, in the pause function I have an alert which displays the value of the variable (just as a test for now).

The issue is that the pause click event does not only alert the current value but also all the previous ones.

What is the cause of this? And what can I do to fix it?

In fiddle example press Start and the press Pause every now and then to see all values.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Limitedmoves/SrWJP/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.butResize').click(function () {
        alert("hello"); 
            GameStart();    
    });

    function GameStart(){
        //Set needed random variables below
        var vSetTimer = 1000 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        var vBarWood = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 400); 

        setTimeout(function () {
        //alert(vSetTimer);
            $('.div').animate({height: vBarWood }, 500);
        GameStart();    
    }, vSetTimer); //Time lenght set from vSetTime variable

    $('.pause').click(function () { //Start pause function
        var vTempTimer= vSetTimer;
        console.log(vTempTimer);    
    });
}
});
```

I have looked around here at stackoverflow and found similar behavior being solved by using "return", but from what I have tried it hasn't helped.

Thanks beforehand! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ju-k's explanation is correct, and offers a working solution. However, another solution could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.butResize').click(function () {
        alert("hello");
        GameStart();
    });

    var vSetTimer;
    var vBarWood;

    function GameStart(){
    //Set needed random variables below
        vSetTimer = 1000 * Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        vBarWood = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);

        setTimeout(function () {

            //alert(vSetTimer);

            $('.div').animate({height: vBarWood }, 500);

            GameStart();    

        }, vSetTimer); //Time lenght set from vSetTime variable
    }

    $('.pause').click(function () { //Start pause function
        console.log(vSetTimer);
    });

});
```

I.e. move the variables to the outer scope, which would also solve it without having to unbind/bind each time.

**EDIT**
As pointed out in the comments, no explanation as to why it behaved as it did in this answer. Here goes:

The reason for the behaviour in the question is, as stated in other answers, because each time GameStart was called, a click-handler was appended to the element(s) that matched the selector ".pause". I.e. first time GameStart runs, a handler with a closure var (vSetTimer) was appended to the ".pause" button. The next time GameStart runs, it'll do the same, etc. This closure does not change, which is why the same number that showed up the first time shows up the second time, followed by the next closure var, and so on.

Comment: This is a good answer to "And what can I do to fix it?". You might add an explanation to "What is the cause of this?"

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am using this solution now. Never knew the solution was this elementary. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Each time `GameStart` gets called, you add a new event handler to the `$('.pause')` element.

So the second time you call `GameStart`, a click on `.pause` will fire 2 functions.

A **simple** solution would be to `unbind` all previously added click handlers, before adding a new one:

```
$('.pause').unbind('click').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

**EDIT:**
For a better and cleaner solution see @Björn Roberg s answer

Comment: You're right, it's not necessary. But as I pointed out, it'd be a **simple** solution.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I tried this and it worked as I needed it to. I will have to read up on unbind now I guess. Thank you again.

Comment: I highly recommend @Björn Roberg s answer, which offers a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrWJP/18/), I've added a cleartimeout and solved your problem.

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

also I put the `randNumber` outside `reSize()` scope.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have implemented parts of this solution as well since it gave me the exact value of the Settimeout() when pressing pause. Thank you!